# Plot contour lines using st_as_sf() work in local Shiny but not on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, r-sf, shinyapps

I have a problem with plot contour lines using `st_as_sf()` in shinyapps.io. I checked all the packages' dependencies and nothing. I know that's in `st_as_sf()` because in my all data set, some contour plot works and don't have any geometry problem with my `stands_extent` file.

My plot works very well in local Shiny RStudio:

[image: map1]

But after publish on shinyapps.io:

[image: map2]

My example below and just only with `Unique ID` CERROCOROADO_003A the plot work:

```
# Packages
require(rgdal)
require(shiny)
require(ggplot2)
require(ggpubr) 
require(dplyr)
require(shinythemes)
require(ggspatial)
require(sf)
require(maptools)
require(lubridate)


# get AOI
download.file(
  "https://github.com/Leprechault/trash/raw/main/stands_example.zip",
  zip_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
)
unzip(zip_path, exdir = tempdir())

# Open the files
setwd(tempdir())
stands_extent <- readOGR(".", "stands_target") # Border
stands_ds <- read.csv("pred_target_stands.csv", sep=";") # Data set
stands_ds <- stands_ds %>%
  mutate(DATA_S2 = ymd(DATA_S2))


# Create the shiny dash
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
  titlePanel(title="My Map Dashboard"),  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable0",
                  label = "Type", 
                  choices = c(unique(stands_ds$PEST)),selected = TRUE ),
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable1",
                  label = "Date", 
                  choices = c(unique(stands_ds$DATA_S)),uiOutput("selectedvariable0")),
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable2",
                  label = "Project", 
                  choices = c(unique(stands_ds$PROJETO)),uiOutput("selectedvariable1")),
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable3",
                  label = "Stand", 
                  choices = c(unique(stands_ds$CD_TALHAO)),selected = TRUE),
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable4",
                  label = "Unique ID", 
                  choices = c(unique(stands_ds$ID_UNIQUE)),selected = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("idSaida"),
      fluidRow(
        splitLayout(plotOutput("myplot"))),
      dateInput(inputId = "Dates selection", label = "Time")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output){
  
  currentvariable0 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable0})
  currentvariable1 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable1})
  currentvariable2 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable2})
  currentvariable3 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable3})
  currentvariable4 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable4})
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    
    #Subset stand
    stands_sel <- subset(stands_extent, stands_extent@data$ID_UNIQUE==currentvariable4())
    
    #Subset for input$var and assign this subset to new object, "fbar"
    ds_sel<- stands_ds[stands_ds$ID_UNIQUE==currentvariable4(),]
    
    #Create a map
    polys <- st_as_sf(stands_sel)
    ggplot() +
      geom_sf(data=polys) +
      geom_point(data=ds_sel,
                 aes(x=X, y=Y), color="red") +
      xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") +
      coord_sf() +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(text = element_text(size=10)) 
  }) 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
##
```

Please, any idea for fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rgeos` package is missing. Add this to your code.

```
library(rgeos)
```

Here it is working on shinyapps.

[image]